# Error Submitting a form in Django - django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: account_deal.company_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a form that takes value from another model, and everything is loaded correctly, but when I submit the data the form is showing the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: account_deal.company_id
```

The consensus is that you have to add blank=True,null=True but that only prevents the error if the user doesn't type any data, in this case, I'm using an auto-generated date, so not sure why am I getting this error.

views.py

```
def close_lead(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        deal_form = DealForm(request.POST)

        if deal_form.is_valid():
            deal_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated the status from open to Close')
            id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
            obj = Leads.objects.get(project_id=id)
            obj.status = "Closed"
            obj.save(update_fields=['status'])

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        else:

            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your Form')
    else:

        id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Leads, project_id=id)

        m = obj.__dict__
        keys = Leads.objects.get(project_id=m['project_id'])

        form_dict = {'project_id':keys.project_id,
                     'agent':keys.agent,
                     'client':keys.point_of_contact,
                     'company':keys.company,
                     'service':keys.services
                     }
        form = NewDealForm(request.POST or None,initial = form_dict)


    return render(request,
                  "account/close_lead.html",
                  {'form':form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from phone_field import PhoneField
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.utils import timezone

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True, unique=True)
    role = models.TextField(blank=True)
    location = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company

class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=100, default="this_is@n_example.com", unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    phone = PhoneField(default="(XX)-XXX-XXX")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.firstname} {self.lastname}'

class Leads(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
                ('Illumination Studies','Illumination Studies'),
                ('Training','Training'),
                ('Survey Design','Survey Design'),
                ('Software License','Software License')
               )
    STATUS = (('Open','Open'),
               ('Closed','Closed'),
               ('Canceled', 'Canceled')
              )
    project_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="agent")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    point_of_contact = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expected_revenue = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    expected_licenses = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS)
    estimated_closing_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CHOICES)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.project_id}'


class CallReport(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (

                ('Phone Call','Phone Call'),
                ('Onsite Meeting', 'Onsite Meeting'),
                ('Client Offices', "Client Offices"),
                ('Other Location','Other Location'),

               )
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    minutes_of_meeting = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    client_POC = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=CHOICES, default='Phone Call')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    ACTeQ_representative = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='agent')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'Call Report for {self.company}, on the {self.date}'

class Deal(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
                ('Illumination Studies','Illumination Studies'),
                ('Training','Training'),
                ('Survey Design','Survey Design'),
                ('Software License','Software License')
               )
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Leads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="project_id")
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="agent")
    service = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CHOICES)
    closing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='client')
    licenses = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    revenue = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Lastly, the form:

```
from .models import Profile, Client, Company, Leads, CallReport, Deal
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from django.forms.fields import DateField


class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('role', 'photo', 'location')

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname',"position",'company','country','email','phone')


class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('company',)

class LeadsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ('project_id','company','agent','point_of_contact','services','expected_licenses',
                  'expected_revenue','country', 'status', 'estimated_closing_date'
                  )
        widgets = {'estimated_closing_date': DateInput()}

class CallForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CallReport
        fields = ('company','title','location', 'ACTeQ_representative','client_POC','minutes_of_meeting','date')
        widgets = {'date':DateInput()}


class DealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = ['agent','project_id','service','client', 'licenses','revenue', 'comments']

class EditLeadsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ('project_id','company','agent','point_of_contact','expected_revenue',
                  'expected_licenses','country', 'status', 'estimated_closing_date',
                  'services')
        widgets = {'date': DateInput()}

class NewDealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = ['project_id','agent','client','company','service', 'licenses','revenue', 'comments']
```

I have already deleted the database and run the migrations, and the error persists.

Comment: The problem you're seeing is that it's trying to create a `Deal` model without a `company` and that column is not nullable. Your `DealForm` does not include `company` as a field, which is why it stays null. So you either need to make that column nullable or to modify your `DealForm` to provide a value for that field.

Comment: @AndréBorie you should have added that as an answer :)

Comment: @AndréBorie spot on, you are right, it is weird because I was concentrated on the NewDealForm, which is the form I'm using, so I would have never imagine that I have to change the DealForm as well, but thanks a lot for your input